# How to avoid a TCP Socket from throwing a SocketException on disconnect?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm working on some C# server project, and it's going quite good.

Today I changed from Async reading, to normal reading, using polling. Now when I was reading async this wasn't a problem, but now it is.

When the client disconnects, the socket throws a SocketException, and that exception causes some pretty long delay. If I don't stop it from throwing that exception, the entire server will freeze for about half a second. And that might not seem worth the trouble, but the server will get a pretty high amount of connects and disconnects, so it really takes too long.

Now I'm already checking the Socket.Connected property, that returns true, but after the read method it returns false.

So does anyone know how to 'update' the status of the connection, before trying to read it?

PS: I *am* catching the exception, it's just that the delay is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typical TCP development, having a connection closed unexpectedly should be an *exceptional* case. You should consider implementing a more graceful system, where the one side first sends a message indicating that it's going to disconnect, that way both sides can then close the connection without any failures.

Bear in mind that activity is required to determine if a connection is closed or not. Per the MSDN docs on [Socket.Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connected.aspx), that property only reflects whether or not the connection was connected *at the time the last operation was attempted*.

If you're doing anything non-trivial with this, you should be isolating your connections with threads (not necessarily one thread per connection, as anything with high traffic would quickly overwhelm the system), but it should not be possible for a single connection to monopolize the entire server, whether that's from a lengthy operation that the connection initiates or a timeout expiration.

Comment: So the answer is: it's impossible? Because they'll most likely be closed properly, but if it's not, I don't want the delay either.

Comment: Basically, yes. And the same exception would have been thrown from your async calls, but I'm guessing that you might not have been finalizing each call with a call to `EndRead`.

Comment: I know that it causes the same exception when using async calls. But then the exception is dealt with async, and it won't block the server.

Comment: See my edit; you shouldn't be writing a server that utilizes only one thread. Out of curiosity, why did you move away from the async approach?

Comment: I never said it wasn't one threaded. The server puts every 10 (customizable) clients on a different thread, and there are about 10 more different threads to deal with specific server components. Like GUI, maps, logging, database connection, timing, etc. But the async approach would cause every client to get a thread, and when the server grows it might get over 1000 clients. And the PC can't run so many threads.
So yes, it won't block the entire server of course, but that also depends on what mode it's running. I can specify the server to wait for each thread to be done, then it kills the srvr.

Comment: That's incorrect; using the `Begin*` and `End*` functions will *not* cause each client to get its own thread.

Comment: Well, what I know about async methods is that they run on the ThreadPool, causing the thread-pool to create new threads, or if the maximum amount of threads is reached, to wait with executing at all. So unless this is not true, and that 2K async methods would all run, and not only 25 of those at the same time, then I can stick with async.

Comment: It's not really possible to generalize (accurately) about the methods in the framework following the async pattern (corresponding `Begin` and `End` functions). Some of them definitely *do* run on the `ThreadPool`, but most of the IO-related functions already have OS-level asynchronous functionality (called Overlapped I/O), and the managed implementations use these, not explicit or implicit threading.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, then I'll stick with the async reading and writing. I'm sure it's okay then :).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Socket is reading from the closed stream to some kind of timeout maybe?
I would just use a second thread, or see if I could change the timeout to 0 after the disconnect?

Comment: Well, actually the stream is only flagged as closed after I try to read.

Comment: Thats weird. Are you closing the socket properly?

Comment: I'm closing the socket on a client, not on the server.

Comment: I think both Sockets should first be closed.

Comment: That's why I'm getting the exception... and there's a huge difference between what is, and what should be.